# When I click the "Replay" button only the GameScene.sks runs, not the GameScene.swift... How do I get both to play at the same time?

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7, skspritenode

New to Stackoverflow so sorry if I posted it wrong! Thanks

My App is a maze game with a time limit, once the time hits 0 the game ends and it goes to a game over screen (separate swift file), this consists of a "Replay" button which when pressed only shows the gamescene.sks file and not the gamescene.swift file (therefore none of the functions work). Is there a way to show both?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
                let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location) //1
                if node.name == "replay" { //2

                    let reveal : SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(1)
                    let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                    self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)

                    let reveal2 : SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(1)
                    let sksScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene.sks")
                    sksScene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                    self.view?.presentScene(sksScene!, transition: reveal2)


                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure you're using your *GameScene* subclass when loading your *GameScene.sks*

```
let skView = self.view as SKView!
let transition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") as GameScene!
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

You only need to use `presentScene` once :]